# I have a column (ride_length) in variable(trips) in factor datatype exported from excel as HH:MM:SS that I would like to convert to minutes

Tags: r

```
#using the glimpse function
ride_length       : Factor w/ 21865 levels
#using the str function
$ ride_length        <fct> 0:12:57, 0:18:29, 1:37:18, 0:13:52, 0:37:17, 0:47:21
```

I would like the new output to read below as

```
$ ride_length        <???> 12.95, 18.4833, 97.3, 13.8666, 37.2833, 47.35
```

Answer (score 1):

We may convert to `hms` and divide by 60

```
as.numeric(hms::as_hms(as.character(trips$ride_length))/60)
[1] 12.95000 18.48333 97.30000 13.86667 37.28333 47.35000
```

#### data

```
trips <- structure(list(ride_length = structure(c(1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 
5L), .Label = c("0:12:57", "0:13:52", "0:18:29", "0:37:17", "0:47:21", 
"1:37:18"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, you can do

```r
with(strptime(as.character(trips$ride_length), "%H:%M:%OS"), 60 * hour + min + sec / 60)
```

though there are limitations, as `strptime` requires hours from 0 to 23, minutes from 0 to 59, and seconds from 0 to 60. If that constraint isn't satisfied, then, with `lubridate`, you can do

```r
library("lubridate")
as.numeric(hms(as.character(trips$ride_length)), "minutes")
```

Answer (score 1):

With `chron` package we could (data from akrun many thanks):

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)

ride_length <- trips %>% 
  mutate(ride_length_minutes = 60 * 24 * as.numeric(times(ride_length))) %>% 
  pull(ride_length_minutes)

ride_length
```

```
[1] 12.95000 18.48333 97.30000 13.86667 37.28333 47.35000
```

Or as new column:

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)
trips %>% 
  mutate(ride_length_minutes = 60 * 24 * as.numeric(times(ride_length)))
```

```
  ride_length ride_length_minutes
1     0:12:57            12.95000
2     0:18:29            18.48333
3     1:37:18            97.30000
4     0:13:52            13.86667
5     0:37:17            37.28333
6     0:47:21            47.35000
```